# how can use react native connect with shared library(.so file)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project and I using shared library (.so) for server. I want to connect between React Native with .so file but I don't know how to connect. Is there anyway or solutions for connect React Native with (.so) file? Thanks

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.42
- Platform: iOS,  Android
- Development Operating System: Windows
- Dev tools: Android Studio 2.3, Android 6.0

Comment: Just place the .so file in `app/src/main/jniLibs/<lib type>/*.so` . That should be all you have to do

Comment: Thanks, I already try but I received error as below:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.demo-1/lib/x86/libmpdemo-jni.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40

Comment: Are you sure there's not something faulty with the .so?

Comment: @Trip: yes, I am sure, In Android project I can get data normally from (*.so) file. But when I used react native I received error as above. This is my source code use in react native project
http://prntscr.com/eql9r5